# iOS Touch Events Rate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, touch

Is it possible to get touch events more often than once per frame. (every ~16 milliseconds for 60 fps)
I've tried this code in my cocos2d app:

```
- (void) touchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    double currTime = CACurrentMediaTime();
    if (_previousTime) {
        NSLog(@"%f", currTime - _previousTime);
    }
    _previousTime = currTime;
}
```

I have tried touchesMoved method in default UIViewController and get the same result: ~16ms between events. Same with other touch methods (touchesBegan, touchesEnded). They are on same kind of a frame grid.
So, is there a way to get touch events more often?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Touch detection is tied to the screen refresh rate, which is 60 Hz on iOS devices.

It doesn't really make sense to receive more touches (or other events) since you can't display any of those in-between values. I have a hunch that maybe you're working with a different kind of problem, namely that a touch can move relatively large distances when moving the finger quickly. The solution to that problem is interpolation and/or adding intermediate points on a line longer than a given threshold.